# hashmap not being updated by new input

Tags: hashmap

I am having an issue with my code not being updated properly when a user decides to update the hashmap. the update section of my code is this

```
    if(comboBoxSelection == "Update"){

        String gradeValue= (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose Grades: ", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, grades, "");
        String creditAmount=  (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose Credit: ", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, credits, "");

        studentObj.courseCompleted(gradeValue.charAt(0), Integer.parseInt(creditAmount));

        studentDatabase.put(iD, studentObj);


    }//end update combobox selection
```

and the method that accepts those changes is

```
public void courseCompleted(char courseGrade, int creditHours){

    if (courseGrade == 'A'){
        totalCredit = 4;
        totalQuailtyPoints = (totalCredit * creditHours);
    }//end course grade A

    if(courseGrade == 'B'){
        totalCredit = 3;
        totalQuailtyPoints = (totalCredit * creditHours);

    }//end course grade B

    if(courseGrade == 'C'){
        totalCredit = 2;
        totalQuailtyPoints = (totalCredit * creditHours);

    }//end course grade C

    if(courseGrade == 'D'){
        totalCredit = 1;
        totalQuailtyPoints = (totalCredit * creditHours);

    }//end course grade D

    if(courseGrade == 'F'){
        totalCredit = 0;
        totalQuailtyPoints = (totalCredit * creditHours);

    }//end course grade F


}//end courseCompleted method
```

if i need to post more of the code please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Technically your hashMap should update. There is a possibility that the gradeValue you get from the JOptionPane doesn't match any of the cases. Or that block of code is never executed. Insert some println statements to check above things.

```
if(comboBoxSelection == "Update")
```

This is not the way to compare strings.

Use equals() method. Because of this your update block may not even be getting called.

`if(comboBoxSelection.equals("Update"))`

Answer (score 0):

i think i figured it out. so for some reason adding this code would display the information i am looking for and it would allow the hashmap to update. the new code is

```
if(comboBoxSelection.equals("Update")){

        if(studentDatabase.containsKey(iD)){

        studentObj = studentDatabase.get(iD);
        String gradeValue= (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose Grades: ", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, grades, "");
        String creditAmount=  (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose Credit: ", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, credits, "");

        studentObj.courseCompleted(gradeValue.charAt(0), Integer.parseInt(creditAmount));

        studentDatabase.put(iD, studentObj);


        }//end makes sure key exists

        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student does not exist");
        }//end else

    }//end update combobox selectio
```